# Unsigned int64 C++ to Java

Tags: java, c++, unsigned-long-long-int

Can the following snippet be successfully converted to Java?

```
u64 magic_table[5] = {
  0x1000000010000000ull,
  0x1000000000010000ull,
  0x1000000000000001ull,
  0x0100000001000000ull,
  0x0000000100000001ull
};

u64 test(u64 magic_sum, int index) {
  u64 before = magic_sum & 0x4444444444444444ull;
  u64 after = (magic_sum + magic_table[index]) & 0x4444444444444444ull;
  return after & ~before;
}
```

Comment: In short: yes. In reality, we don't "convert code", or otherwise write code for you. Please try something, post your Java code, and we'll try to help you after that.

Comment: I think a solution to your problem would be to consult a basic [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Answer (score 4):

A long in Java is 64-bit, but signed. However the 64-bits are still there for you to do whatever you would like with. So yes, I would say you can convert the C++ code to Java.

Comment: I've tried that approach using long, however the result is just a huge number instead of having a number with its bits set.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono What do you mean "just a huge number".  `0x1000000010000000ULL` _is_ a huge number.

Comment: It depends on whether he needs to consider the actual values.  (Since he's using hex, he probably doesn't, but you never know.)  Not all of the values in a `uint64_t` are representable in a Java `long`.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that `u64` is `uint64_t`, formally, no.  Java has no
type which is capable of representing all of the values of
a `uint64_t`.  Practically, it depends on what you are doing
with the values.  Java *does* have a 64 bit integral type, and
if you're just looking at bits, rather than the integral value
(or if the actual values would fit in a `int64_t`), then you can
just use `long`.

The integer type suffix will just be `L`, of course, and not
`ULL`, but otherwise (for the values you give):

```
long magicTable[] = { 
    0x1000000010000000L,
    0x1000000000010000L,
    0x1000000000000001L,
    0x0100000001000000L,
    0x0000000100000001L
};
```

should work.  Java will even allow things like
`0x800000000000000L`, even though the actual value cannot be
represented in a `long`.  (The resulting *value* will be
ngative.)

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have time to deal with the differences in the languages(C++ vs. Java), just use [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) and you can run whatever  C/C++ code in Java easily and efficiently.